# Add and remove mousemove listener on window with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, addeventlistener, mousemove, removeeventlistener

I'm trying to add an event listener on the `window` when an object is clicked, and then remove that event listener when the object is again clicked.

When a `Card` component is clicked, state `isCardMoving` is toggled on or off.

I added a `useEffect` to watch `isCardMoving`. When `isCardMoving` is toggled on, it should add a `mousemove` event listener to the window that triggers the `handleCardMove` function. This function just logs the coordinates of the mouse.

if I click the card again, `isCardMoving` will be false, and I would expect the event listener on the window to be removed inside the `useEffect`.

What happens, though, is that the event listener will get added when `isCardMoving` is `true`, and then will not be removed once `isCardMoving` is `false`.

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [isCardMoving, setIsCardMoving] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isCardMoving) window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleCardMove);
    else window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleCardMove);
  }, [isCardMoving]);

  const handleCardMove = (event) => console.log({ x: event.offsetX, y: event.offsetY });

  return <Card onClick={() => setIsCardMoving(!isCardMoving)} />;
};
```

I then tried to set a `ref` on the window thinking that maybe I would need a previous reference to the window for some reason:

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [isCardMoving, setIsCardMoving] = React.useState(false);

  const windowRef = React.useRef(window); // add window ref

  // update window ref whenever window is updated
  React.useEffect(() => {
    windowRef.current = window;
  }, [window]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // add and remove event listeners on windowRef
    if (isCardMoving) windowRef.current.addEventListener('mousemove', handleCardMove);
    else windowRef.current.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleCardMove);
  }, [isCardMoving]);

  const handleCardMove = (event) => console.log({ x: event.offsetX, y: event.offsetY });

  return <Card onClick={() => setIsCardMoving(!isCardMoving)} />;
};
```

This seems to have the same effect as before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't remove an event listener like this in React or other virtual DOM-based applications. Due to the nature of virtual DOMs libraries, you must remove the event listener in the unmount lifecycle, which is in React hooks and is available within the `useEffect` itself. So you have to do it like below with the return keyword. It will do the same thing as `componentWillUnmount` in class base components:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isCardMoving) window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleCardMove);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleCardMove);
}, [isCardMoving]);
```

**Working Demo:**

[image: CodeSandbox]

### Update

As @ZacharyHaber said in the comments, the main reason behind this behaviour is that your `handleCardMove` function will be redefined on every render, so to overcome this situation, we need to unbind the event from the window on each render with the `useEffect` callback. You can also make your initial code work using the `useCallback` approach. Still, you also need to add the previous `useEffect` callback to your component to make sure the event listener will remove in the component unmount cycle, it is a bit more coding, but this one will do the same as the above approach.

```js
const handleCardMove = React.useCallback((event) => {
   console.log({ x: event.offsetX, y: event.offsetY });
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (isCardMoving) window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleCardMove);
  else window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleCardMove);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleCardMove);
}, [isCardMoving, handleCardMove]);
```

**Working Demo:**

[image: CodeSandbox]

Comment: It's less about how the virtual dom libraries work, and more that `handleCardMove` is being redefined on every render. And removing event listeners require a handle to the function that was initially added. For example, using `useCallback((e)=>console.log(e),[])` would make it so the initial code would work

Comment: @SMAKSS @Zachary Haber thanks, that makes sense. I'll have to remember this...it's calling the returned callback when `isCardMoving` is updated the second time (and put back in the off position)? Going to have to find some resources about this

Comment: I've used the `useEffect` return like this before for unmount, but I didn't think to use it for on/off functionality like this

Comment: @rpivovar Yeah, Zachary is truly right. If you put your function inside a `useCallBack` and add it to the `useEffect` dependencies array you can use it without `return` and with the initial approach that you tried.

Comment: Although, don't do that, because then the event listener won't be cleaned up when the component unmounts, so it's not the ideal way of doing it. Hence why I just commented about the `useCallback` method as a note rather than put up a separate answer. This answer is the correct way of doing it, just with a slight shift on the ideas behind it :)

Comment: Woah -- just tried wrapping the `handleCardMove` in a `useCallback`. I'll stick to the return in the useEffect...but thanks for the insight to you both. Really helping me level up my understanding of both of these hooks.